# Surprising equivalences and non-equivalences regarding this.type

Tags: scala, reflection, traits, path-dependent-type, singleton-type

It appears to make a difference whether you refer to `this.type` from inside a Trait or from the scope where the object is created, with surprising results.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait Trait {
  val ttag = typeOf[this.type]
  println(s"Trait constructor: $this")
}

object Instance1 extends Trait

object Instance2 extends Trait

println(typeOf[Instance1.type] =:= typeOf[Instance2.type])  // Should be false
println(Instance1.ttag =:= Instance2.ttag)                  // Should be false
println(Instance1.ttag =:= typeOf[Instance1.type])          // Should be true
```

Here's the output:

```
false    // As expected: the singleton types of two objects are different.
Trait constructor: $line9.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Instance1$@58c46295
Trait constructor: $line10.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Instance2$@452451ba
true     // But the this.type tags are equivalent
false    // and the this.type tag is not equivalent to the singleton type.
```

So, there are two distinct objects, but apparently each is getting an equivalent type tag for its `this.type`, which is not equivalent to the `.type` of the object as seen from an enclosing scope.

Is this a compiler bug, or, if not, could you explain why this behavior makes sense?

(I'm running Scala 2.11.2. I've tried it with a `self` alias for `this`, with the same result.)

Comment: For what it's worth, when I run your code I get an internal compiler error. So, a compiler bug doesn't seem too unlikely. As another way to experiment, a more direct way to get at a similar idea is to have a method that returns the type of a local object.

Comment: @Owen Based on our conversation below, my search through the spec, and a search through the issues database, I went ahead and posted my [first Scala bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9439). I hope it's not a duplicate or actually not a bug!

Comment: My current understanding (building from Owen's and Jason Zaugg's comments): each path-dependent type has a “prefix” telling where to find the object within its scope. Type equivalence-checking looks at the prefix, not the object itself (which exists only at run-time and might never get created). So, inside `Trait`, `this.type` has prefix `Trait`, resulting in type `Trait.this.type`—for all instances.  `Instance1.type` has a prefix saying that the object is defined in the top-level scope, with name `Instance1`, resulting in type `Instance1.type`—different than inside `Trait`.

Answer (score 2):

The following program prints false and then true. To my mind, there should be no material difference between these two cases (though that's really more of an opinion; I can't really say if there's a reason or not):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Test2 extends App {
  def foo(): Type = {
    object a
    typeOf[a.type]
  }

  println(foo() =:= foo()) // false

  trait Trait {
    val ttag = typeOf[this.type]
  }

  object Instance1 extends Trait

  object Instance2 extends Trait

  println(Instance1.ttag =:= Instance2.ttag) // true
}
```

Comment: I think that since the two objects created by the calls to `foo` are different, it's correct that their singleton-type type tags are different. Creating an object violates referential transparency—or does it? Maybe this _is_ the key to what I’m asking about.

Comment: The [spec says](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#object-definitions) that an object definition defines a single object of a _new class._ So far, I haven't found anything to indicate whether a single object definition inside a function definition should define one object or as many objects as times the function is called. But it does appear that the two `Instance`s, having separate definitions, should have separate types.

Comment: @BenKovitz Passing `-Yprint:typer` could be informative here... it will desugar object definitions into a class definition and a new instance creation, so you can see exactly how many instances are created.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been playing a bit with `-Xprint:typer` and `-Ytyper-debug`. (Note slightly different flags, in case it matters.) Here's my current hazy guess at what's going on: Since `a` is in scope, the TypeTag macro makes a [SingleType](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types%24SingleType) that refers to `a`. But inside the Trait, all we get is a [ThisType](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types%24ThisType) that knows only the trait, not the object.

Comment: I'm still not too clear on the difference between a SingleType, SingletonType, and ThisType, though. But anyway, your suggestion of putting the object in a local scope might be just what I need to make a workaround for what I'm actually doing. More experimentation to come…

Comment: Thinking about this some more, I still don't get it. Both results from `foo` are `SingleType(NoPrefix, TermName("a"))`. So how can `=:=` tell them apart?

Comment: @BenKovitz I don't know how it works under the hood. It seems to me that each singleton type `foo.type` where `foo` is a stable identifier is uniquely identified at runtime by a tuple of the type path of `foo` and the identity of the actual object `foo`.

Comment: Well, that might be the central question: Is a singleton type defined at compile-time or run-time? Hypothesis _du jour_: it's at compile-time for objects defined in a static scope (like inside an object), and it's at run-time for objects defined in a dynamic scope (like inside a function) but there's still a compile-time signature that enables type-checking. That's only a guess, though. I haven't found it discussed in the spec, though it could be in there somewhere.